# If a non-Jew steals is he liable to the death penalty?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, gezel-stealing, capital-punishment, noachide-laws

Stealing is a Noahide commandment. If a non-Jew violates a Noahide commandment, he is condemned to be put to death. Does this mean that if he steals a shave perutah ( שוה פרוטה, a tiny amount) or something he must be put to death?

Comment: That's a valid syllogism

Comment: Do you have a source for violating a Noachide commandment being a capital offense?

Comment: See Sanhedrin 57a

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Gemara](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=62&format=text) says that a non-Jew is liable to death for stealing *less* than a penny. "אמר רבי חייא בר אבא אמר רבי יוחנן בן נח נהרג על פחות משוה פרוטה ולא ניתן להשבון"

The [Rambam](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e509.htm) agrees.

Comment: FTR the Rambam also [says](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/b201.htm#2) it is prohibited biblically for a Jew to steal less than a penny as well.

Comment: See http://wikinoah.org/index.php/Capital_Punishment_in_Noahide_law

Comment: a perutah is more then a penny, as much as 6-7 cents.